# Problemas con ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, .net, clickonce

tengo un problema al momento de querer hacer el ejecutable de una aplicación que hice en Visual Studio, como la aplicación requiere permisos de administrador ya que conecta automáticamente a wifi, tengo que agregarle la petición si o si, pero el problema es que cuando intento hacer el ejecutable me marca un problema con ClickOnce el mensaje que aparece es el siguiente:
ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'
ya intente desactivando ClickOnce pero al final se activa solo de nuevo

Comment: El ejecutable se crea al compilar en la carpeta bin de tu proyecto ¿tu te refieres al empaquetado? Si das click derecho->publicar se activara automáticamente. ClickOnce no permite instalar aplicaciones que se ejecuten como administrador (a menos que cumplas una serie de requisitos, certificados,etc), de hecho es justo para que todos puedan instalarlo desde cualquier drive. Yo te recomiendo que uses otro tipo de sistema de instalacion como Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects, InnoSetup, NSIS, etc. O tambien puedes usar .NET que te da otras opciones de publicacion.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución y decidí responderme por si algún día alguien tiene el mismo problema, la solución es ir a las propiedades de el proyecto donde se encuentra el formulario, en security y signing desmarcan las opciones donde dice "ClickOnce" una vez hecho eso descarguen el Installer Projecs según su versión de visual studio, aquí el link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20Installer%20Projects&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=vs2019&sortBy=Relevance
y generan el instalador ya sin ningún problema solicitara los permisos de administrador claro siempre y cuando tengan ya configurado el manifest.

Comment: Muy buen aporte, pero pon algo de codigo y pantallazos para que esto quede bien documentado